# Jquery Fold attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have 4 panels on my website that look like folders with tabs. They are all places separate (top left, bottom left, top right, bottom right). When I press the expand button on one of them the fold effect makes the other 3 fold out like folders. So my issue here is I'm not to experienced with jquery just kind of got into it. So 1, the tabs overlap the expanded div then eventually fade out. When I minimize it the other folder come back but they kind of all jump around and eventually end of in their right spots but it looks so messy.

So can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the jquery

```
$("#button3").click(function () {
    if (a > 0) {
        $(".schedule, .personal, .caseLoad, .notifications").css({
            "width": "100%",
            "position": "static",
            "margin-top": "0px",
            "height": "300px"
        }, 3000);
        $("#effect, #effect1, #effect2, #effect3").show("fold", 1000);
        $('[id="calculator"]').hide();
        $("#personalTab, #notificationsTab, #scheduleTab, #caseTab").show("fade", 1000);
        $("#navPersonal, #navNotifications, #navSchedule, #navCase").hide("fade", 1000);
        $("#scheduleTab, #caseTab, #notificationsTab, #personalTab").css({
            "width": "20%",
            "position": "static",
            "right": "20%"
        }, 3000);
        a = a - 1;
        n = 0;

    }
    else {
        $("#effect, #effect1, #effect3").hide("fold", 1000);
        $("#scheduleTab, #caseTab, #navNotifications, #personalTab").hide("fade", 1000);
        $("#navSchedule, #navCase, #notificationsTab, #navPersonal").show("fade", 1000);
        $(".notifications").css({
            "height": "600px",
            "width": "200%",
            "position": "absolute",
            "margin-top": "20px",
            "right": "20px"
        }, 3000);
        $("#notificationsTab").css({
            "width": "100%",
            "position": "absolute",
            "right": "92%"
        }, 3000);
        a = a + 1;
        n = n + 1;
    }
});
```

and the panel to one of the panels. They are all similar in size and jquery just different button click

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div id="notificationsTab" class="tab" style="background-color: #AD816B;">
                <a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;Notification</a>
                <div id="button3" class="button4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toggler2">
                <div id="effect2">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="notifications" runat="server" class="notifications" UpdateMode="Conditional"
                        ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="mCustomScrollbar content3 fluid light">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 15%">
                                            Action
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 55%">
                                            Description
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 30%">
                                            Date Added
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So many lines! First of all, concatenate your selectors when the function applied to each is the same. `$("#effect1, #effect, #effect3, etc etc").hide("fold", 1000);`

Comment: Welp I'm doing that now and yea looks a lot nicer haha!

Comment: I prefer to store references to known logical (jquery) elements in an init method. Doing a lot of DOM traversal on a click can create serious performance issues, and should be considered an anti-pattern.